# parsing XML content and loading to a database .NET6

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, api

I'm trying to parse through an XML file (4 level nested) and, using a model builder, append those values to a local database. And I'm struggling with that part, so I would really appreciate some help. Also, I'm really new to this language and framework as you will see.

```
<machines>
  <machine>
    <manufacturer>SDBSDBSDKB</manufacturer>
    <name>NKSDBSDKJBDSKBDB</name>
    <description>
      <DEU>JBSDSBDKKJ</DEU>
      <ENU>NDSIDBSSKBKJB</ENU>
    </description>
    <type>DSIBDSDBJKSD</type>
    <number>0-200-84-3151</number>
    <cfg_r>
      <connection>JJSBJSBKDSJDBS</connection>
      <cfg_r_text> JHBSJBDISBKDBSKDBSBDKBSDKLN </cfg_r_text>
      <cfg_r_physical_unit_abbreviation> KBJSBDKSKJBSDSKJB 
      </cfg_r_physical_unit_abbreviation>
      <cfg_r_displaytext> JSDHSDVSDVSDDSKBJDB 
      </cfg_r_displaytext>
    </cfg_r> 
  </machine>
</machines>
```

Here's a comparable segment of an xml file that I'm trying to work with. In particular I'm trying to make a model builder for a 'machine' dbset (level 2). A "description" object is part of the attributes of this machine dbset; here i used a Foreign key to map it. Like say:

```
[ForeignKey(nameof(MachineDescription.Id))]
public int DescriptionID { get; set; }
```

And here's a description of the MachineDescription class

```
public class MachineDescription
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string DEU_desc { get; set; }

        public string ENU_desc { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(Machine.Id))]
        public MachineDescription MachineId { get; set; }
    }
```

And finally, this is what I have with my model builder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Machine>().HasData(from machine in placeholder.Elements("machine")
                                                          select new Models.Machine
                                                          {
                                                              Id = idx++,
                                                              Manufacturer = machine.Element("manufacturer").Value,
                                                              Name = machine.Element("name").Value,
                                                              MachinesDecriptions.Append(
                                                                  new MachineDescription
                                                                  {
                                                                    Id = descID++,
                                                                    DEU_desc = machine.Element("description").Element("DEU").Value,
                                                                    ENU_desc = machine.Element("description").Element("ENU").Value,
                                                                    MachineId = descID
                                                                  }),



                                                              Type = machine.Element("type").Value,
                                                              Number = machine.Element("number").Value,
                                                          });
```

I would appreciate some help with getting my MachineDescription referenced in my Machine class. And manually adding them is not an option

Comment: (1) Your XML sample is NOT a well-formed XML. Please fix it. (2) you can pass entire XML as a parameter to a stored procedure, shred it there, and INSERT into the database.

Comment: Sorry about that, just got it corrected

Answer (score 0):

Like @Yitzhak Khabinsky mentioned in a comment, it's probably better to just pass the xml to your database and allow it to be parsed there.

Here's some sample code to get you started.

```
Declare @xml xml;
Set @xml = N'<machines>
  <machine>
    <manufacturer>SDBSDBSDKB</manufacturer>
    <name>NKSDBSDKJBDSKBDB</name>
    <description>
      <DEU>JBSDSBDKKJ</DEU>
      <ENU>NDSIDBSSKBKJB</ENU>
    </description>
    <type>DSIBDSDBJKSD</type>
    <number>0-200-84-3151</number>
    <cfg_r>
      <connection>JJSBJSBKDSJDBS</connection>
      <cfg_r_text> JHBSJBDISBKDBSKDBSBDKBSDKLN </cfg_r_text>
      <cfg_r_physical_unit_abbreviation> KBJSBDKSKJBSDSKJB 
      </cfg_r_physical_unit_abbreviation>
      <cfg_r_displaytext> JSDHSDVSDVSDDSKBJDB 
      </cfg_r_displaytext>
    </cfg_r> 
  </machine>
</machines>'

Select  Node.Data.value('manufacturer[1]', 'varchar(100)') As Manufacturer,
        Node.Data.value('name[1]', 'varchar(100)') As Name,
        Node.Data.value('description[1]/DEU[1]', 'varchar(100)') As Description_DEU,
        Node.Data.value('description[1]/ENU[1]', 'varchar(100)') As Description_ENU,
        Node.Data.value('type[1]', 'varchar(100)') As Type,
        Node.Data.value('number[1]', 'varchar(100)') As Number,
        Node.Data.value('cfg_r[1]/connection[1]', 'varchar(100)') As Cfg_Connection,
        Node.Data.value('cfg_r[1]/cfg_r_text[1]', 'varchar(100)') As Cfg_Text,
        Node.Data.value('cfg_r[1]/cfg_r_physical_unit_abbreviation[1]', 'varchar(100)') As Cfg_Abbreviation,
        Node.Data.value('cfg_r[1]/cfg_r_displaytext[1]', 'varchar(100)') As Cfg_DisplayText
From    @xml.nodes('machines/machine') Node(Data)
```